# MeteorJS project with redis-livedata package not returning object from redisCollection.hgetall as expected

Tags: meteor, redis

The MeteorJS method "get.jade" is not returning jade object to client as expected. I'm using  redis-livedata and manuel:reactivearray packages, and Redis is functioning locally correctly. I have put console.log in the code where there is a problem is returning server side data to client

**jades.html**

```
<template name="jades">
    {{#if jadeslength}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="user-card" id="swipe">
                <img src="{{jade.img}}" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-container">
                    <h5>{{jade.name}}, {{jade.gender}}</h5>                 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="one-half column">
                <button class="no" type="button">no</button>
            </div>
            <div class="one-half column">
                <button class="button-primary yes" type="button">yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{else}} 
        <div class="row">
            <button class="button-primary search-jades" type="button" id="search">search</button>
        </div> 
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

**jades.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Session } from 'meteor/session';
import './jades.html';

Template.jades.onCreated(function () {
    var jades = new ReactiveArray([]);
    Session.set({'jadeId':""});
});

Template.jades.helpers({
    jade: function() {
        return jades.list();
    },

    jadeslength: function() {
        var jades = jades.list();
        return jades.length;
    },
});

Template.jades.events({

...

    'click .search-jades' () {
        Template.instance.jades = [];
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var client_location = {"lat": position.coords.latitude, "lng": position.coords.longitude};
                if (client_location) {
                    var lng = client_location.lng;
                    var lat = client_location.lat;
                    Meteor.call('client.profile', (error, result) => {
                        if (error) { 
                            FlashMessages.sendError(error, 3000);
                        } else { 
                            var user_profile = result;
                            Session.set({'user_profile': user_profile});
                            var prefer = user_profile.prefer;
                            switch (prefer) {
                                case "cis women":
                                    Meteor.call('search.cw', lng, lat, (error, result) => {
                                        if (error) { 
                                            FlashMessages.sendError(error, 3000);
                                            return;
                                        } else { 
                                            searched = result; 
                                            if (searched.length == 0) {
                                                FlashMessages.sendWarning("no more providers found in your area", 3000);
                                            } else {
                                                for (var found of searched) {
                                                    var user_profile = Session.get('user_profile');
                                                    var right = user_profile.right;
                                                    if (!(found._id in right)) { 
                                                        Template.instance.jades.push(found._id);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                var jadeId = Template.instance.jades.pop();
                                                console.log(jadeId); // returns ofQj98LBQWrSJ8gJs on client
                                                if (jadeId) {
                                                    Meteor.call('get.jade', jadeId, (error, result) => {
                                                        if (error) { 
                                                            FlashMessages.sendError(error, 3000); 
                                                        } else { 
                                                            Session.set({'jadeId': jadeId});
                                                            Session.set({'jade': result});
                                                            console.log(result); // returns undefined on client
                                                        }
                                                    });     
                                                } else {
                                                    FlashMessages.sendWarning("no more providers found in your area", 3000);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                break;
                                case "trans women":
...
```

**methods.js**

```
    'get.jade': function(jadeId) {
        var redisCollection = new Meteor.RedisCollection("redis");
        redisCollection.hgetall(jadeId, function(error, object) {
            if (error) { 
                console.log(error); 
            } else { 
                console.log(object);  // returns { name: 'alex', img: 'null', gender: 'cis woman' } on server
                return object; 
            }
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the method as follows:

```js
'get.jade': function(jadeId) {
        var redisCollection = new Meteor.RedisCollection("redis");
        return redisCollection.hgetall(jadeId)
    },
```